# Read AndroidManifest programmatically

Tags: android, android-manifest

I tried to read the whole content of AndroidManifest of all installed applications but no luck. 
I tried to use:

```
AssetManager am = getActivity().createPackageContext(packageName, 0).getAssets();
XmlResourceParser xml = am.openXmlResourceParser("AndroidManifest.xml");
```

also

```
class JarFile
```

but no luck. I'm looking for something, what will give me the **WHOLE CONTENT** of this file for every app.

Comment: what information are you trying to read ? the PackageManager can help you with that.

Comment: "I tried to use" -- few apps will have a second copy of their `AndroidManifest.xml` file in their project's `assets/`.

Comment: Reading of whole manifest contnent is one of the feature of my developing app. CommonsWare - I don't understand, what do you mean